# Delete Unregistered Users after a Week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I have ActionMailer send an email when a user registers. I then generate a random :sign_in_token with the user so that the user can activate his account. Once a user activates his account via email, the users :registration_complete boolean is set to true.

**How can I delete users saved in the database a week after they have been created if they have not activated their account?**

This is my current solution. But I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

I get this ERROR message

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `-' for :created_at:Symbol):
```

USER MODEL

```
after_create :delete_unregistered_users

def delete_unregistered_users
  User.where("created_at <= ?", :created_at - 1.week && :registration_complete == false).each do |user|
    user.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: :created_at is a symbol, what is its value..?

Comment: If you get an error message, you can bet it's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def delete_unregistered_users
  User.where("created_at <= ? AND registration_complete = ?", Time.zone.now - 1.week,false).destroy_all
end
```

Comment: for whatever reason this deleted every user in the database lol

Answer (score 2):

```
def delete_unregistered_users
  User.where("created_at <= ? AND registration_complete = ?", Time.zone.now - 1.week,false).each do |user|
    user.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: this `:registration_complete == false`

Answer (score 2):

```
def delete_unregistered_users
  User.where("created_at <= ? && registration_complete=?", '#{Time.zone.now - 1.week}',false).each do |user|
     user.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: still @Monk_Code u are wrong, "#{Time.zone.now - 1.week}" is correct

Comment: i get this error PGError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "#{Time.zone.now - 1.week}"
LINE 1: ...LECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (created_at <= '#{Time.zo...

Comment: i got the same error when i use '#{Time.zone.now - 1.week}', if u want i can show u my console trace

Comment: @surge have you used User.where("created_at <= ? && registration_complete=?","#{Time.zone.now - 1.week}",false)

Comment: @user32655018 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (created_at <= '2014-01-27 11:35:03 UTC' && registration_complete='f')